# Rewriting the Geometric Product in 3D Space?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I'm reading a passage from *Geometric Algebra for Physicists*, and in section 2.4.1 there's a train of logic I'm not quite understanding.
I'll copy it word for word, with *italics* being my comments/concerns:

To explore [geometric products] further, let's form the product of the vector $\mathbf{a}$ with the bivector $\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{c}$. From the associative and distributive properties of the geometric product we have: $\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{a}\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}\mathbf{b})=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}\mathbf{c}\mathbf{b})$. *(I understand this part)* We now use the rearrangement $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}=2\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}$ *(I don't get this step)* to write $\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{c})=(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c}-(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b}-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b})=2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c}-2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{c}\mathbf{b})\mathbf{a}$. *(I definitely don't understand this one. Where did the 2s come from and the sign change?)* Therefore $\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{c})-(\mathbf{b}\wedge\mathbf{c})\mathbf{a}=2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c}-2(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b}$.*(It suffices to say that I really don't understand this step because I don't get the prior two.)*

Comment: It looks to me as though there is a misprint in the first equation you don't understand. In the rearrangement, replace c with a.

Comment: @Peter So maybe the book's wrong? The book has c there. But it is called a rearrangement, so maybe one can arrive at that equation through the first one?

Comment: If c is replaced by a you get a rearrangement of $a.b= \frac{1}{2}(ab+ba)$, which is standard.

Comment: @Peter Holy crap, you're right! My book has a misprint in that equation which partially erases the tail in the a, so I thought it was a c. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So this arose because my book had a misprint in an equation. Once that was pointed out the equations make sense. Thanks to @Peter for the help.